# Custom Form Field Render using UpdateView not Saving Data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use custom HTML to render form field elements. However, now the data is not saving. The data is saving if I use the default `form.as_p` method.

Related template:

```
<!--DOES NOT SAVE DATA-->
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.description }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

```
<!--SAVES DATA-->
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Related UpdateView:

```
class ProfileEditView(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileCreateForm
    template_name = 'update_profile_backup.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        print(obj.user == self.request.user)
        return obj.user == self.request.user
```

Related ModelForm:

```
class ProfileCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = 'platform', 'content_niche', 'youtube_channel_id', 'description','profile_img', 'v_id_0', 'v_id_0_title', 'v_id_0_desc', \
                 'v_id_1', 'v_id_1_title', 'v_id_1_desc', 'v_id_2', 'v_id_2_title', 'v_id_2_desc'
```

Is it because the custom render method is not validating the form data? If so, how would I do that with an updateview?

Comment: It presumably doesn't work because you are only showing the description field, and at least one of the other fields is required; plus, you are not displaying any of the form errors.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't include all the form fields.